# Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

On my site I use several php pages on which I have to call data from a mysql db using prepared statements.

Suddenly I'm having this intermittent error message "Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements" and stops the page from loading. I wait a little while and every thing works normal again.

I ran a `show global status like 'com_stmt%'` and this is what it shows:

```
Com_stmt_close  11305830
Com_stmt_execute    12109430
Com_stmt_fetch  0
Com_stmt_prepare    12109475
Com_stmt_reset  0
Com_stmt_send_long_data 75
```

On all pages I close the statement and the PDO only once at the bottom of the page, like this:

```
$mysqli->close();
$pdo = null;
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1 - If I have to open 2 or 3 queries on one single PHP page, do I have to close them one by one? or do I close them all at the end of the page? with the above script?

2- If the answer for the first question is "you can close them just once at the end of the page" then please tell me why am I having this error?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: are you calling `prepare` in a loop or something? If so, that's entirely wrong. you prepare a statement ONCE, then execute it multiple times in a loop. e.g. `prepare(); while() { execute(); }`. doing `while() { prepare(); execute(); }` entirely negates the purpose of preparing a statement.

Comment: I run it this way: first `$result=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT blah blah blah)` then `$result ->bind_param(blah blah)` then `$result ->execute();` then `$result ->store_result();` then `$result ->bind_result(blah blah)` and finally `while ( $result->fetch() ) {}` Is this right?

Comment: Once the error has been triggered and the page is no longer able to load, is there a way to force all connections to close? ....If one does nothing, do they close by themselves?